# How to publish angular 8 module to NPM

Tags: angular, npm, angular-module, npmjs

I'm working on a angular module, which I need to share between several angular applications. so I have decided to publish it to npmjs, but I couldn't find a good documentation for that. does any one have a good documentation which covers my requirement.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5). It should work with angular8 as well.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, But this is about angular library. What I'm looking for is publishing a angular module

Comment: That's the way it works: Put the module you want to share into a library and import the library in other projects. 
You can have a look at one of my packages (certainly really small, with only one module): https://github.com/DanielHabenicht/ngx-vcard